# Youtube iframe API 'start' freezes loading

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the Iframe API to load dinamically a player at a determined time. This is the code:

```
    new YT.Player('vi', {
        videoId: video_url,
        height: 332,
        width: 590,
        playerVars: {
            start: 126,
            autoplay: 1,
            showinfo: 0,
            autohide: 1,
            rel: 0
        }
    });
```

The player is rendered in the website and it is positioned on the second 126 but keeps loading infinitely. If I remove "start: 126 from playerVars it works great.

Comment: is this happening on flash or html5 player?

Comment: It's happening on HTML5 player